# How to refactor EventListener function in Java Script

Tags: javascript

I have a top navigation menu that each item anchors to a different section on my page. But the sections are initially hidden (display: none), and by clicking on the menu item it appears.

I made this code but it's not efficient and I have to create a bunch of variables. How can I refactor this?

```
const menuLink = document.querySelectorAll(".menu__link");
const firstSection = document.querySelector('#section1');
const secondSection = document.querySelector('#section2');
const thirdSection = document.querySelector('#section3');
const fourthSection = document.querySelector('#section4');

for (item of menuLink) {
    item.addEventListener("click", function showContent (event) {

        if (event.target.id === "menu__section1") {
            firstSection.style.display = "block"; } 

        if (event.target.id === "menu__section2") {
            secondSection.style.display = "block"; }

        if (event.target.id === "menu__section3") {
            thirdSection.style.display = "block"; }

        if (event.target.id === "menu__section4") {
            fourthSection.style.display = "block"; }
 })
}
```

Here is the HTML:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Landing page</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/style.css">
    <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Antic+Slab&family=Henny+Penny&display=swap" rel="stylesheet">
</head>

<body>
    <div class="grid__container">
        <header class="page__header">
            <nav class="navbar__menu">
                <ul id="navbar__list" class="menu__list">
                    <li><a class="menu__link" id="menu__section1" href="#section1">More motives</a></li>
                    <li><a class="menu__link" id="menu__section2" href="#section2">Images</a></li>
                    <li><a class="menu__link" id="menu__section3" href="#section3">Reviews</a></li>
                    <li><a class="menu__link" id="menu__section4" href="#section4">Maybe later</a></li>  
                </ul>
            </nav>
        </header>
        <div class="banner__hero">
            <h1 class="heading__page">Landing Page </h1>
            <div class="banner__center">
                <ul class="motives__list__banner">
                    <li class="motives__item">Great motive</li>
                    <li class="motives__item">Great motive</li>
                    <li class="motives__item">Great motive</li>
                    <li class="motives__item">Great motive</li>
                </ul>
                <q class="quote__review"><b>Great review from one of your customers</b><br><br> Lorem ipsum dolor sit
                    amet,
                    consectetur adipiscing elit. Morbi fermentum metus faucibus lectus
                    pharetra dapibus. Suspendisse potenti. Aenean aliquam elementum mi, ac euismod augue. Donec eget
                    lacinia ex. Phasellus imperdiet porta orci eget mollis.Sed convallis sollicitudin mauris ac
                    tincidunt. Donec bibendum, nulla eget bibendum consectetur, sem nisi aliquam leo, ut pulvinar
                    quam nunc eu augue. Pellentesque maximus imperdiet elit a pharetra. Duis lectus mi, aliquam in
                    mi quis, aliquam porttitor lacus. Morbi a tincidunt felis.</q>
            </div>
            <button type="button" class="page__button">Buy here!</button>
            <p class="introduction__text">Why someone would buy your product? (up to 5 lines)</p>
            <button type="button" class="page__button">More info here!</button>
        </div>
        <main class="page__main">
            <section id="section1" data-nav="More motives" class="your-active-class section__box">
                <h2 class=" heading__section">More motives</h2>
                <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Morbi fermentum metus faucibus lectus
                    pharetra dapibus. Suspendisse potenti. Aenean aliquam elementum mi, ac euismod augue. Donec eget
                    lacinia ex. Phasellus imperdiet porta orci eget mollis. Sed convallis sollicitudin mauris ac
                    tincidunt. Donec bibendum, nulla eget bibendum consectetur, sem nisi aliquam leo, ut pulvinar
                    quam nunc eu augue. Pellentesque maximus imperdiet elit a pharetra. Duis lectus mi, aliquam in
                    mi quis, aliquam porttitor lacus. Morbi a tincidunt felis. Sed leo nunc, pharetra et elementum
                    non, faucibus vitae elit. Integer nec libero venenatis libero ultricies molestie semper in
                    tellus. Sed congue et odio sed euismod.</p>
            </section>
            <section id="section2" data-nav="Images" class="section__box section__2">
                <h2 class="heading__section">Images/ Screenshots of your product</h2>
                <img src="img/product.jpg" alt="Product" class="product__image">
                <p>Morbi porttitor auctor enim, sit amet sagittis odio suscipit eu. Vestibulum rutrum mollis dolor,
                    non tristique lacus luctus ac. Integer in ipsum eget nisl pellentesque imperdiet ac vel sapien.
                    Class aptent taciti sociosqu ad litora torquent per conubia nostra, per inceptos himenaeos. In
                    mi dui, sagittis in erat id, rutrum efficitur nisi. Fusce varius risus enim, vitae accumsan eros
                    tincidunt sit amet. Phasellus blandit finibus eros eu suscipit. Morbi eget dictum leo. Integer
                    eu accumsan tellus. Pellentesque est mauris, consectetur non elit a, elementum posuere lorem. In
                    sit amet mattis urna. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Mauris volutpat
                    ornare massa eget iaculis.</p>
            </section>
            <section id="section3" data-nav="Reviews" class="section__box section__3">
                <h2 class="heading__section">Good reviews of your product</h2>
                <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Morbi fermentum metus faucibus lectus
                    pharetra dapibus. Suspendisse potenti. Aenean aliquam elementum mi, ac euismod augue. Donec eget
                    lacinia ex. Phasellus imperdiet porta orci eget mollis. Sed convallis sollicitudin mauris ac
                    tincidunt. Donec bibendum, nulla eget bibendum consectetur, sem nisi aliquam leo, ut pulvinar
                    quam nunc eu augue. Pellentesque maximus imperdiet elit a pharetra. Duis lectus mi, aliquam in
                    mi quis, aliquam porttitor lacus. Morbi a tincidunt felis. Sed leo nunc, pharetra et elementum
                    non, faucibus vitae elit. Integer nec libero venenatis libero ultricies molestie semper in
                    tellus. Sed congue et odio sed euismod.</p>
            </section>
            <section id="section4" data-nav="Maybe later" class="section__box section__4">
                <h2 class="heading__section">Maybe later?</h2>
                <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Morbi fermentum metus faucibus
                    lectus
                    pharetra dapibus. Suspendisse potenti. Aenean aliquam elementum mi, ac euismod augue. Donec eget
                    lacinia ex. Phasellus imperdiet porta orci eget mollis. Sed convallis sollicitudin mauris ac
                    tincidunt. Donec bibendum, nulla eget bibendum consectetur, sem nisi aliquam leo, ut pulvinar
                    quam nunc eu augue. Pellentesque maximus imperdiet elit a pharetra. Duis lectus mi, aliquam in
                    mi quis, aliquam porttitor lacus. Morbi a tincidunt felis. Sed leo nunc, pharetra et elementum
                    non, faucibus vitae elit. Integer nec libero venenatis libero ultricies molestie semper in
                    tellus. Sed congue et odio sed euismod.</p>
                <button type="button" class="page__button">Let's keep
                    talking</button>
            </section>
        </main>
        <footer class="page__footer">
            <h1 class="heading__section">Add me!</h1>
            <p><a href="https://github.com/Bmg1612" class="contact">Github</a></p>
            <p><a href="https://www.linkedin.com/in/bruno-gurgel/" class="contact">Linkedin</a></p>
        </footer>
    </div>
    <script src="js/app.js"></script>
</body>

</html>
```

And the CSS for this part:

```
.your-active-class,
.section__2,
.section__3,
/* 
    The review will only appear in this part if the user is on a desktop.
    Otherwise, it will appear, in the section of reviews (3).  
    */
.quote__review {
  display: none;
}

.section__4 {
  text-align: center;
  display: none;
}
```

Comment: how are you initially hiding the sections?

Comment: @Henrydev with css display: none

Comment: I don't see that in your code?

Comment: I didn’t put the CSS because I thought  would get to messy the question. I will update now

Comment: you don't need to declare variables for each element, I simplified it and posted a solution. Let me know if that helps :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, first of all you need to get rid of the **for loop**, and this could help. I tested it with your code and it works just fine.

```
const ul = document.querySelector('ul');
  ul.addEventListener('click', function(event){
  var currentSelection = event.target.id;
  var sectionNumber = currentSelection.slice(-1);
  var element = document.querySelector('#section'+sectionNumber);
  element.style.display = "block";
});
```

Comment: Thanks so much Henry! I was stuck int his for a time now hahaha. It worked perfectly :)

Comment: Welcome! I'm glad it could help :-)